# Android: Generator for action bar overflow icon

Tags: android

Hello is there a generator online for the actionBarOverflowIcon?

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Is a great generator for other items, but it's missing the actionbaroverflowicon generator.

Would like to do this other than having my designer create a set for my visual design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clearly see it in there just go to clip art and select the overflow button which is located top left of the list. [click here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fcore_overflow.svg&name=ic_action_core_overflow&theme=custom&color=33b5e5%2C60) to see the styled overflow button.

Comment: Oh I have a plugin running ... Why I though everything was broken on the site. See it now thank you!